# Showing index of files on home page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, indexing, directory, web-hosting

I have a site on 000webhost and the site is only for indexing, however, I am having issues on getting it to show the default apache index on the home page, rather than 000webhost version of "Hooray, your free website has been started!"
I need the URL to be a short as possible, so I want to simply type the website, instead of creating a folder to see an index.

The Internet has not been much help, I know it's probably .htaccess but not had much look with options like "Options +Indexes" a friend of mine told me to look up "Apache htaccess rule for auto index" but again not found anything useful.

If I create a folder, and then go to said folder, I can remove "?dir=" to see a directory like this.
[image: Removing ?dir= from a folder]

This is what I want the homepage to look like. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you show  your htaccess   contents?

Comment: It has nothing in it.